# Regex to extract version from string

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I have a string which has below value

> String1=winos-app-1.2.0-4.20120308.InLinuxOS.x86_64

I need to extract only version from this string which is "1.2.0-4"

I have tried regular expression as mentioned below with sed

```
sed -ne 's/[^0-9]*\(\([0-9]\.\)\{0,1\}[0-9][^.]\).*/\1/p'
```

but I am only getting result "1.2.0-", missing number after "-" which is 4. I tried correcting it but it is returning null.

Kindly, advise

Answer (score 1):

how about grep:

```
grep -Po "(?<=-)[\d.-]*(?=.\d{8})"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n 's/^.*-\([0-9.]*-[0-9]*\)\..*$/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, and should also account for any of the version numbers being more than one digit long.

```
String1=winos-app-1.2.0-4.20120308.InLinuxOS.x86_64
sed -n 's/[^0-9]*\(\([0-9]\+\.\)\{0,2\}[0-9]\+-[0-9]\+\).*/\1/p' <<< "$String1"
1.2.0-4
```

BTW, this will also match version strings like (which from your question is not clear if you want this behavior or not):

```
1-1
1.2-1
```

If you want to enforce `w.x.y-z`, you could use this:

```
sed -n 's/[^0-9]*\(\([0-9]\+\.\)\{2\}[0-9]\+-[0-9]\+\).*/\1/p' <<< "$String1"
```

Comment: Thank You ! very much.
Could you also suggest a reg ex for checking versions
What if I like to check any version in 1.0.0 release may be "1.0.0-1" or "1.0.0-2" or "1.0.0-3" and I just need to check for what update version is it "-1 or -2 or -3" 
"1.0.0-1 or 1.0.0-2 or 1.0.0-3" 
what regex can I use ?
"sed -ne s/1.0.0\-[0-9]\1/p" would this work ?
Thanks !
sed -n 's/1.0.0\-[0-9]'

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

`[^0-9]*\(\([0-9]\.\)\{0,2\}[0-9][^.]\).*`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try parameter expansion:

```
string1=winos-app-1.2.0-4.20120308.InLinuxOS.x86_64
string2=${string1%".${string1#*-*-*-*.}"}
version=${string2#*-*-}
printf "%s\n" "$version"
```